# HDP cluster how define disk partition?

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

When installing HDP cluster, I tried to use the best practice from Hortonworks for how to define the disk partition using the following procedure: [documentation](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.2/bk_cluster-planning-guide/content/file_system.html)

I am using Ambari 2.0 for installing my stack. The Hadoop default installation path is `/hadoop/xxx`.
Is there a way to tell Ambari to use the best practice from the link above instead of `/hadoop`?
If not what is the best way to do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended practices is to setup the environment before you start installing HDP via ambari. Ambari will not perform any of the activities for you as mentioned in the resource you have shared.

Comment: ok so how can i configure this using ambari after he allready installed the data node and the name node at /hadoop?